# Excel 2010 - Filling cell with blank cell using formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, formula

In Excel 2010,

I've problem in filling a value with formula. Let me explain.

When a cell C3 is filled with value 50 , C4 should change to "paid", if filled with <20, C4 should change to "Pending". If C3 is empty, then C4 should also be an empty cell.

`C3 = 35`; `C4= Paid`;
`C3 = 17`; `C4= Pending`;
`C3 = [empty]`; `C4= [empty]`;

for this which formula need to work on.

Comment: Hi, please consider accepting one of the answers below. Although it's not mandatory, it's a nice gesture to those who have tried to help you. It will also make the question appear solved to anyone who might have a similar question in the future. Thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

In the equation below, I've assumed that any value below 20 will return "Pending". You have not specified what should happen if there are negative values, or something equivalent.

```
=IF(C3>=20, "Paid", IF(C3<20, "Pending", ""))
```

Note that I've assumed that it should return "Paid" for values `>=20`, not `>20`. If this is incorrect then change the conditionals to:

```
=IF(C3>20, "Paid", IF(C3<=20, "Pending", ""))
```

Explained:

```
If C3 is larger than 20, return Paid
If C3 is not larger than 20, but not empty, return Pending
If both conditions above are false, Return nothing.
```

Comment: Thanks, but the point is when I enter some values in cell C3 which is equal to C2, C4 should change to _"paid"_. If C3<C2, C4 should be _"Pending"_. Otherwise C3 will be empty and C4 should be blank.   'C2 = C3; C4= **Paid**;'  /  'C2>C3; C4=**Pending**; / 'C2=10, C3=[empty]' 'C4=[empty]'

Comment: [tour], and [ask] and [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Stewie Griffin,

Here I got what I need.

```
=IF(D7<=F7,"Paid",IF(AND(F7<>"",F7<>0),"Pending",""))
```

now this says the *paid* and *pending* and shows **blank** if its empty..